# How to create a login via django rest framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-csrf

I am cracking my head about something. I want to use session authentication on my API. I use the django restframework.

What i didn't found in the documentation is how to obtain the csrf token (and session-id) initially, as response after a post login call. (I don't mind to get it either via a get when opening the login page)

It's sounds trivial to me, but i can not find the answer.

Is there someone here who can help me in the right direction?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

It's in the [topic section](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/ajax-csrf-cors/#csrf-protection) of the documentation.

CSRF is a Django thing and you'll find more about it in the [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/csrf/#ajax)